# Calculating the boundaries of rising values in a sequence

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have records with a continuous `id` and fluctuating pressure values `druck`. My goal is to find out between which values a pressure increase occurs and accordingly get the lowest and highest id of this range. I already have a solution using classic SQL, but I would be interested in a more efficient solution.

Here are some typical entries:

```
create table produktion ( id int, druck numeric (5, 2 ) );
insert into produktion
values (1, 1.35), (2, 1.37), (3, 1.45), ( 4, 1.48), ( 5, 1.51), ( 6, 1.39),
       (7, 1.53), (8, 1.55), (9, 1.62), (10, 1.39), (11, 1.32), (12, 1.28);
```

I expect this result:

```
========================
| erste_id | letzte_id |
|=======================
|        1 |         5 |
|        6 |         9 |
========================
```

Here is the currently used query:

```
SELECT p1.id AS erste_id,  -- first id
       p2.id AS letzte_id  -- last id
FROM   produktion AS p1,
       produktion AS p2
WHERE  p1.id < p2.id AND
       NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                   FROM   produktion AS p3,
                          produktion AS p4
                   WHERE  p3.druck <= p4.druck AND
                          p4.id = p3.id - 1 AND
                          p3.id BETWEEN p1.id + 1 AND p2.id OR
                          p3.id = p1.id - 1 AND p3.druck < p1.druck OR
                          p3.id = p2.id + 1 AND p3.druck > p2.druck )
```

### Update

I forgot to mention that at equal values, a sequence is considered interrupted.

### Update 2

I made some small changes to FatFreddy 's query so that it meets my requirements.

```
WITH
     find_boundaries AS (
   SELECT id,
          CASE WHEN lag(  druck, 1, druck ) over ( ORDER BY id ) <  druck AND
                    druck <  lead( druck, 1, druck ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) THEN NULL
               WHEN lag(  druck, 1, druck ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) <  druck AND
                    druck >= lead( druck, 1, druck ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) THEN 'end_run'
               WHEN lag(  druck, 1, druck ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) >= druck AND 
                    druck <  lead( druck, 1, druck ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) THEN 'start_run'
          END AS row_type
   FROM produktion ),

     start_boundary AS (
   SELECT id,
          row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS correlated_start_row
   FROM   find_boundaries
   WHERE  row_type = 'start_run' ),

     end_boundary AS (
   SELECT id,
          row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS correlated_end_row
   FROM   find_boundaries
   WHERE  row_type = 'end_run' )

SELECT s.id AS anfang,
       e.id AS ende
FROM   start_boundary AS s
       JOIN end_boundary AS e
         ON s.correlated_start_row = e.correlated_end_row
ORDER  BY 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing a EXPLAIN ANALYZE on your query i come up with (12 entries)

```
Planning time: 0.184 ms
Execution time: 3.525 ms
```

i can give you a query with more planning time but less execution time

```
Planning time: 0.290 ms
Execution time: 0.269 ms
```

100 entries

```
yours
    Planning time: 0.193 ms
    Execution time: 10457.269 ms
mine
    Planning time: 0.342 ms
    Execution time: 1.175 ms
```

1000 entries

```
yours
    no result after 5 minutes
mine
    Planning time: 0.343 ms
    Execution time: 5.866 ms
```

1000000 entries

```
yours
    no result after 5 minutes
mine
    Planning time: 0.348 ms
    Execution time: 5217.038 ms
```

replacing some of your nested loops by hash joins.
using some window functions
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-window.html
my
query looks like that:

```
with temp_flow as
(
select
id,
case when 
    id = 1 and lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)   <=  produktion.druck then 'fall' 
when 
    id = 1 and lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  >  produktion.druck then 'start raise' 
when 
    lag(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  < produktion.druck  and    lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)   > produktion.druck then 'raise'
when 
   lag(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  < produktion.druck  and    lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)   <=  produktion.druck then 'end raise'
when 
   lag(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  = produktion.druck  and    lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)   <=  produktion.druck then 'fall'
when 
   lag(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  >=  produktion.druck  and    lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)   >  produktion.druck then 'start raise'
else 'fall'
end as way,

lag(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id) as beforelag,
produktion.druck,
lead(produktion.druck,1, 0::numeric) over(order by id)  as afterlead
from produktion
order by id
),

temp_start as  
(
select
id,
row_number() over () as xrow
 from temp_flow
where temp_flow.way = 'start raise'
order by id
),

temp_end as 
(
select
id,
row_number() over () as xrow
 from temp_flow
where temp_flow.way = 'end raise'
order by id
)

select
temp_start.id as first,
temp_end.id as last
from 
temp_start
join temp_end on temp_end.xrow = temp_start.xrow
```

in your setup it is not declared what shall be done with equal druck, so you may put somewhere a >= instead a > 
and you could use digits instead e.g. 'start raise' which i used for readability which should be faster as text compare.

happy testing with big data on your system.

edit: correct result doinig some more cases, fetching some strange cases

Comment: TBH with the amount of test data provided, I doubt the stats are reliable. Plus we don't know what indexes he might have on his actual table, which would again alter the plans.

Comment: @ eurotrash you are right, maybe Nouba does a comparison

Comment: @FatFreddy Unfortunately, the requirements are not met. For example, if the second value is `1.33` instead of `1.37`, I expect the first id in the first record to start at 2 and not at 1. However, the second record starts with 2 instead of the 6th record.

Comment: @Nouba i did an edit to my query, hope it fullfills the requirements and did some testing with some random generated data

Comment: @FatFreddy Thank you, that's satisfactory.